# Why does my javascript's form loop return NAN while adding array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add all array elements with basic for loop for some reason, my variable 'result' return NaN.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let result = 0;
const arraySum = (arr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    result = arr[i] + result
  }
  console.log(result)
}
arraySum(array)
```

Please use basic looping to answer, I tried .reduce method but want to use basic loops
Thank you

Comment: @TalmacelMarianSilviu If you're going to give an answer, post it in the Answer section, not a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition of `i <= arr.length` should be using `i < arr.length`

The length of the array is 5 but the index of the last number is 4, so you don't want `<=` there.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let result = 0;
const arraySum = (arr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result = arr[i] + result
  }
  console.log(result)
}
arraySum(array)
```

Answer (score 2):

Length start at 1, so you need to set < operator in your loop :

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let result = 0;
const arraySum = (arr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result = arr[i] + result
    console.log(result)
  }
  console.log("result = ", result)
}
arraySum(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this problem is that the array has a length of 5 and the last index is 4. When the loop is at index = 5 there is no element at position 5. The result will therefore be `undefined`. To avoid this problem, the for loop should be like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
```

or

```
for(const i in arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You put '<=' in the for loop but you must use just '<'.
if array = [1,2,3] then length = 3 but array index goes from 0 to 2 not 3

Answer (score 0):

the  "<=" shoud be placed by "<"

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let result = 0;
const arraySum = (arr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
    result += array[i];
  }
  console.log(result);
};

arraySum(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try, if simple enough:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let result = 0;
arraySum = (arr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result += arr[i]
  }
  console.log(result)
}
arraySum(array)
```